# Fundamental Theorem of Projective Geometry for Finite Fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I was trying to understand the proof that the automorphism group of a projective plane over a finite field $F_q$  (denoted $PG(2, q)$) is $P\Gamma L(3, q)$, ie. elements $PGL(3, q)$ composed with field automorphisms of $F_q$ acting coordinate-wise. It is clear that $P\Gamma L(3, q) \leqslant Aut(PG(2, q))$, and I read that the reverse inclusion is true due to the Fundamental Theorem of Projective Geometry. I have seen a proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Projective Geometry in Artin's "Geometric Algebra," but it uses some deeper concepts in Algebraic Geometry. I was wondering if there is a simpler proof for the finite field case?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please put all math text in your post inside math mode, not just the occasional symbol. If you need help with MathJax, you may wish to consult  [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), the [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), the [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) or the [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).